# catching setDateValue with an NSDatePickerCell

Tags: cocoa

I could have sworn I was able to make a custom NSDatePickerCell, override the setDateValue method, and catch anytime the date was changed. It doesn't seem to work now.

Does anybody know how to catch anytime the date value of a date picker changes? Adding an observer to the keypath doesn't work either...

Comment: What control is the cell in? If it's an NSDatePicker, did you remember to set the custom class of the control's cell in IB?

Comment: It is in my own custom datepicker control and i did override the cellClass method.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)datePickerCell:(NSDatePickerCell *)aDatePickerCell validateProposedDateValue:(NSDate **)proposedDateValue timeInterval:(NSTimeInterval *)proposedTimeInterval;
```